# Local crate not found when trying to update edition via cargo fix

Tags: rust, rust-crates, rust-bindgen, bindgen

**Context:**
I have a local C library called 'libmaths' that then uses Bindgen to create a 'libmaths-sys' crate that is locally stored in the same directory as my project.

**Issue:**
I want to use some of the features in the 2021 edition of Rust and currently my project is built off 2018. I am trying to update the project by following the instructions at:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-fix.html

> Run cargo fix --edition. Consider also using the --all-features flag if your project has multiple features. You may also want to run cargo
> fix --edition multiple times with different --target flags if your
> project has platform-specific code gated by cfg attributes.
>
> Modify Cargo.toml to set the edition field to the new edition.
>
> Run your project tests to verify that everything still works. If new
> warnings are issued, you may want to consider running cargo fix again
> (without the --edition flag) to apply any suggestions given by the
> compiler.

To run cargo fix --edition I am told by the compiler to remove the edition="2018" in cargo toml. Following this I receive a compile error stating that libmaths-sys cannot be found. The code compiles and executes normally in 2018 but not without this edition tag.

I can not find anyone with a similar issue, this is my first stackoverflow question so not sure how best to show my code given its a context of a small project.

**Error code**

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `libmaths_sys`

 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use libmaths_sys::*; // lib.rs in sys crate
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `libmaths_sys`?
```

**File Structure and general overview of project**

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── libmaths
│   ├── add.c
│   ├── add.h
│   └── subtract.c
├── libmaths-sys
│   ├── build.rs
│   ├── Cargo.lock
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── src
│   │   └── lib.rs
│   └── wrapper.h
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── lib.rs
    └── main.rs
```

libmaths contains add.c that returns a + b and subtract.c which returns a - b, with a header add.h directing to both .c files

The Rust code generated by bindgen is attached via lib.rs in the libmath-sys crate which links to the OUT DIR which I have omitted from the tree to save 200 lines of file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Solomon Ucko directed me to, rustup update held the key.

```
Running rustup update produced:
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: syncing channel updates for '1.48-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: checking for self-updates

  stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)
    1.48-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.48.0 (7eac88abb 2020-11-16)

info: cleaning up downloads & tmp directories
```

In the end, rustup was using the old 1.48 version and not the installed 1.59 version. 
To switch to the newer vesion I ran:

```
rustup default stable
```

I then could follow the instructions from the link in the original question to change the edition.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating `edition="2018"` to `edition="2021"`; otherwise [it defaults to `edition="2015"`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-edition-field) which [requires usage of `extern crate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#no-more-extern-crate).

Comment: I receive this error when I try that: error: failed to parse manifest at `.../project/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  failed to parse the `edition` key

Caused by:
  this version of Cargo is older than the `2021` edition, and only supports `2015` and `2018` editions.

Comment: @Jambalaya Try updating Cargo first, then. To be able to use the `2021` edition, you'll need to anyways. If you're using Rustup, [`rustup update`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/basics.html#keeping-rust-up-to-date) should be enough.

Comment: I run rustup and this is the current version, the error is still the same when I try and run it.                                                                                                                        info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: syncing channel updates for '1.48-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: checking for self-updates

  stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)
    1.48-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.48.0 (7eac88abb 2020-11-16)

info: cleaning up downloads & tmp directories